# Can't create a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, mysql-cluster

I want to test mysql cluster.

I installed, configured and ran. But I can't create a table connected to my engine=ndbcluster.

I got this error `ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'user_database.user_table' (errno: 157)`

Everything is connected correctly.

Someone as an idea? Please!

Comment: Can you post the query? are all the primary keys set?

Comment: This question might better be asked on dba.stackexchange.com. I think error 157 means that one of the SQL nodes isn't connected to the storage engine... or it might just be something simple wrong with the SQL statement being used to create the table.

Comment: my query was create table test(id int) engine=ndbcluster;                   All nodes are connected so that's why i don't understand.

Comment: Can you share the value of : `$ ndb_mgm
ndb_mgm> show` You are most probably running different version of mysql and ndb.